# How to update this camera code using CameraX current version?

Tags: android, android-camerax

This is the code used to take photo (you can pick either front or back camera):

```
class CameraActivity extends AppCompactActivity {
    
    ActivityCameraBinding binding;
    CameraX.LensFacing mLensFacing = CameraX.LensFacing.BACK;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityCameraBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        binding.btnCameraSwitch.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            onClickSwitchCamera();
        });
    }

     public void onClickSwitchCamera() {
        CameraX.LensFacing newLensFacing;
        if (mLensFacing == CameraX.LensFacing.FRONT) {
            newLensFacing = CameraX.LensFacing.BACK;
        } else {
            newLensFacing = CameraX.LensFacing.FRONT;
        }

        try {
            if (CameraX.hasCameraWithLensFacing(newLensFacing)) {
                mLensFacing = newLensFacing;
                bindCameraUseCases();
                return;
            }
            Toast.makeText(this, "Camera is not supported...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (CameraInfoUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void bindCameraUseCases() {

        CameraX.unbindAll();

        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();

        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        PreviewConfig previewConfig = new PreviewConfig
                .Builder()
                .setTargetAspectRatio(new Rational(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels))
                .setTargetResolution(new Size(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels))
                .setLensFacing(mLensFacing)
                .build();

        Preview preview = new Preview(previewConfig);

        preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener(output -> {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) binding.viewFinder.getParent();
            parent.removeView(binding.viewFinder); //binding.viewFinder is a TextView object
            parent.addView(binding.viewFinder, 0);

            binding.viewFinder.setSurfaceTexture(output.getSurfaceTexture());
            updateTransform();
        });

        ImageCaptureConfig imageCaptureConfig = new ImageCaptureConfig
                .Builder()
                .setTargetAspectRatio(new Rational(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels))
                .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CaptureMode.MIN_LATENCY)
                .setLensFacing(mLensFacing)
                .build();

        ImageCapture imageCapture = new ImageCapture(imageCaptureConfig);

        binding.btnCameraCapture.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            File file = new File(getExternalMediaDirs()[0], System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
            imageCapture.takePicture(file, new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageSaved(@NonNull File file) {
                    // save captured images on given directory

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull ImageCapture.ImageCaptureError imageCaptureError, @NonNull String message, @Nullable Throwable cause) {

                }
            });
        });

        CameraX.bindToLifecycle(this, preview, imageCapture);
    }
}
```

Some users (mostly using Oppo running Android 11) ocasionally complain the app crashes after taking image. I still have no clue what the real cause is. Perhaps because it uses the rather old, alpha CameraX (1.0.0 alpha05). I decide to upgrade to the latest stable CameraX (1.3.0), unfortunately some classes/functions cannot be resolved due to API changes, e.g `CameraX.unbindAll()` or `CameraX.bindToLifeCycle(...)`. This is my attempt:

```
class CameraActivity extends AppCompactActivity {
    
    ActivityCameraBinding binding;
    int mLensFacing = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA.getLensFacing();
    ProcessCameraProvider processCameraProvider;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityCameraBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        binding.btnCameraSwitch.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            onClickSwitchCamera();
        });
    }

     public void onClickSwitchCamera() {
        CameraX.LensFacing newLensFacing;
        if (mLensFacing == CameraX.LensFacing.FRONT) {
            newLensFacing = CameraX.LensFacing.BACK;
        } else {
            newLensFacing = CameraX.LensFacing.FRONT;
        }

        try {
            ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);
            processCameraProvider = cameraFuture.get();

            /*
            How to update this??

            try {
                if (CameraX.hasCameraWithLensFacing(newLensFacing)) {
                    mLensFacing = newLensFacing;
                    bindCameraUseCases();
                    return;
                }
                Toast.makeText(this, "Camera is not supported...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (CameraInfoUnavailableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            */

        }
        catch (ExecutionException ee){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception: "+ee.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ie){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception: "+ie.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        
    }

     protected void bindCameraUseCases() {

        processCameraProvider.unbindAll();
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        /*
        How to update this?

        PreviewConfig previewConfig = new PreviewConfig
                .Builder()
                .setTargetAspectRatio(new Rational(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels))
                .setTargetResolution(new Size(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels))
                .setLensFacing(mLensFacing)
                .build();

        Preview preview = new Preview(previewConfig);

        preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener(output -> {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) binding.viewFinder.getParent();
            parent.removeView(binding.viewFinder); //binding.viewFinder is a TextView object
            parent.addView(binding.viewFinder, 0);

            binding.viewFinder.setSurfaceTexture(output.getSurfaceTexture());
            updateTransform();
        });

        ImageCaptureConfig imageCaptureConfig = new ImageCaptureConfig
                .Builder()
                .setTargetAspectRatio(new Rational(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels))
                .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CaptureMode.MIN_LATENCY)
                .setLensFacing(mLensFacing)
                .build();

        ImageCapture imageCapture = new ImageCapture(imageCaptureConfig);

        binding.btnCameraCapture.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            File file = new File(getExternalMediaDirs()[0], System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
            imageCapture.takePicture(file, new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageSaved(@NonNull File file) {
                    // save captured images on given directory

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull ImageCapture.ImageCaptureError imageCaptureError, @NonNull String message, @Nullable Throwable cause) {

                }
            });
        });

        CameraX.bindToLifecycle(this, preview, imageCapture);
        */
    }
}
```

Still no idea to replace the commented parts.
Perhaps there's any updated code example I can study?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/main/CameraXBasic has the latest code sample for CameraX.